# How to load prefixed json files in i18next?

Tags: i18next

My project is working well with **i18next** library. This is my files working:

**i18n/index.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
// import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import pt from './locales/pt/common.json';
import en from './locales/en/common.json';

const options = {
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  lng: 'en',

  resources: {
    pt: {
      common: pt,
    },
    en: {
      common: en,
    },
  },

  fallbackLng: 'pt',

  ns: ['common'],

  defaultNS: 'common',

  react: {
    wait: true,
  },
};

i18n.init(options);


export default i18n;
```

**i18n/locales/en/common.json**

```
"editor": {
  "sidebar": {
    "header": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**i18n/locales/pt/common.json**

```
"editor": {
  "sidebar": {
    "header": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, I need to prefix my json files with `en` and `pt-BR`. This way, my project stop working. Does anyone have a simple solution?

**i18n/locales/en/common.json**

```
"en" {
  "editor": {
    "sidebar": {
      "header": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**i18n/locales/pt/common.json**

```
"pt-BR" {
  "editor": {
    "sidebar": {
      "header": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on [Gitbub](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/472) and @jamuhl answered. His solution is:

```
resources: {
  pt: {
    common: pt[pt-BR],
  },
  en: {
    common: en.en,
  },
},
```